# UIButton doesn't seem to have a selected state title in iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ios7

This error only appeared in iOS7 - I can't set UIButton to display it's selected state. Neither on the simulator, nor a device. Am I missing something?

#### Regular state

[image: button unselected]

#### Selected state (should display Ace of clubs)

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to change the button type from `System` to `Custom`. `System` option corresponds to the [`UIButtonTypeSystem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW35), which has a default styling built in.

Comment: @MorganWilde It's not an addition, it's a replacement: the old "UIButtonStyleRoundedRect" is gone, all its occurrences have been silently replaced with `UIButtonTypeSystem`. Don't you love when your framework provider just does it behind your back? ;-)

Comment: I had to keep track of my own "selected" state since I couldn't disable that tint selected highlight. I still use the default behavior of the iOS7 UIButtonStyleRoundedRect (fade out on tap), but I wanted my own selected image/behavior, since I couldn't work around that selected state.

Comment: fantastic man caught an eye and saved so much time as its not an issue but since iOS7 many things have changed